# EF6 Max-pool-size reached with using statement?

Tags: entity-framework-6, connection-pooling, dispose, dbcontext, using-statement

I created a small application in MVC5 using EF6 (database first) and [jtable.org](http://www.jtable.org/) (a JQuery plugin to create AJAX based CRUD tables).

I only interact with the database using stored procedures. Even though I create the dbcontext in the using block for every single stored procedure call I make, I get the Max pool reached exception:

> "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 
>   The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

I've spent most of my day trying to figure out what could be wrong, with little success, as the dispose of the dbcontext, disposes the connection too...

Even I've read blogs that say there's no need to call dispose...
http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.VNKTTJ2sWkE

Every single db call I have, it's similar to the ones below, all dbcontexts are created in the using block :

```
 public IEnumerable<Jobs_Get_Result> GetJobs(int categoryId, int startIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        using (var _context = new JobEntities())
        {
            var jobs =  _context.Jobs_Get(categoryId, startIndex, pageSize).ToList();
            return jobs;
        }
    }
```

I use database first, model and dbcontext created by EF.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution?